# WP : Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Screen::render_screen_reader_content

Tags: wordpress

Installed User Login History plugin on my wordpress application, while visitng the user login history plugin page getting the below error message from wordpress.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Screen::render_screen_reader_content()

Searched in google but didn't get valid answer, most of the answers are related to upgrade wp only.

My wp version : 4.2.4

Comment: What is the full error message with the line number? It seems like there is a bug with the plugin which the plugin developer will need to fix.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Screen::render_screen_reader_content() in D:\xmapp\xampp\htdocs\gts\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\user-login-history\admin\class-user-login-history-wp-list-table.php on line 1110

Comment: It seems like the plugin is missing an include file to the WP Screen class. The developer will need to fix the plugin and provide an update.